# Is there a better way to check a string against the names of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter

I am currently trying to create a function that given the string of one variable to return the results of an array with the same name, with the intent to use this to return only the twitter profiles that are needed.

For example, if the variable profile is equal to ManUtd, then return the array ManUtd and its contents.

The array ManUtd will contain all the players on twitter who play for that club which can then be used to return only those twitter profiles.

so far my initial thought is to do something such as:

```
var ManUtd = [
    // array containing all ManUtd twitter players
]

function checkTeam(profile){
  if ( profile == ManUtd ){
    // use the array ManUtd 
  } else if {
    // the rest of the possible results 
}
```

This isn't very efficient and seems rather verbose a solution. Is there a better way to achieve these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make global variables called, eg, ManUtd.  Instead make an object that contains keys and the values you want:

```
var teams = {
  'ManUtd': [the array you mentioned],
  'Arsenal': [some other array],
  //etc
};
```

Then get the arrays like this:

```
function checkTeam(profile){
  if (teams[profile]) {
    return teams[profile];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. Use a dictionary. Store all your array in the dictionary, and retrieve the right one later with the key.

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionary#mapping-types-dict